# System.Net mail settings using Network Solutions hosted email

Tags: c#, system.net.mail

I am trying to use my email service through Network Solutions (NetSol) so that emails sent via the application come from our domains service@ourdomain address.

I cannot seem to make it work, and I am not sure it is even doable since its a webmail service which I can access in a browser using a url like http://mail.ourdomain.com.

According to their site, the smtp settings can be found here
[NetSol smtp](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/pop-imap-settings/)

Using that information I set up my mail settings as follows

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
    <network host="smtp.ourdomain.com" port="587" userName="service@ourdomain.com" password="xxxxxxxx" enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

I know the password is correct as I'm able to login to my mail in the webbrowser so I don't believe its a credentials error although the error in the method is erring on the credential piece.

```
private async Task SendMailMessageAsync(MailMessage msg)
    {
        var acct = Username;
        var pwd = Password;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        using (var mailClient = new SmtpClient())
        {
            if (acct != string.Empty && pwd != string.Empty)
            {
                var credentials = new NetworkCredential(acct, pwd);
                mailClient.Credentials = credentials; //ERRING HERE
            }
            await mailClient.SendMailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
```

Is anyone familiar with the proper setup for NetSol professional email?

**UPDATE:**

For some reason, my code edit in the answer I accepted wasn't accepted. So here is the code, in working order based on the comments in the accepted answer.

```
public void SendNetSolEmail()
    {
        var sender = "whatever@yourdomain.com";
        var pass = "yourpassword";
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage(sender, "sendto_emailaddress", "Hi there", "This method works fine!");
        var mailClient = new SmtpClient("mail.yourdomain.com", 587)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sender,pass),
            EnableSsl = false,  //important for Network Solutions mail
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        };
        mailClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
```

Comment: try adding this line 
`mailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;`

Comment: I would also suggest running code without the `async and await` and put into a console application and see if the code works .. and wrap the `mailClient.SendMail(msg)` around a try catch .. not even sure why you need to send mail Async.. but try to get it to work without Async first..

Comment: @MethodMan...shouldn't the config file, with the Network setting handle that. As to the async, I was just messing around with that method as I know it works and i was just trying to test how to get this working.

Comment: you are not making sense.. `I know it works and i was just trying to test how to get this working` why don't you try some of what was suggested and stop messing around .

Comment: I am in the process of doing that. And it still errs with the following error...Exception Details: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: I also tried it with a non-async mail method and its still erring. It's a credential error again, which Im faily sure is configuration related.

Comment: sounds like you are not using the correct credentials then..

Comment: Credentials are right, they work when logging in via web portal. The dig down error in mailClient is...ServicePoint = 'mailClient.ServicePoint' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' so my guess is the smtp settings either are incorrect or won't work for this mail provider.

Comment: try explicitly adding this line `mailClient.EnableSsl = true`

Comment: no good there either. I'm on with NetSol for an hour and they clueless about what I'm inquiring about. If i get it working Ill post it.

Comment: why don't you try the same code using the `using System.Net.Mail;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple working example of connecting to NetSol's smtp

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailMsg = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("mail.domain.com", 587);
mailMsg.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username@domain.com", "password");
mailMsg.SendMailAsync("username@domain.com", "someone.somewhere@somedomain.com", "Hi Someone", "Body of the email");
```

and the last note as I see you have ssl enabled; Here it is direct from NetSol:

Note - Make sure you are not chosing and SSL type, this option should be turned off, or "None" should be selected.

Comment: I edited your code to what worked for me as your OP didn't work and i accepted the answer. Thank you.